# Deleting the first element of a vector and freeing the memory in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have been trying to find a way to delete the first element of a vector.

```
vector<int*>    vec;
\\elements get added to the vector throughout the code

if( GetNumIntsInVec() != 0){
    this->vec.erase(this->vec.begin());
}
```

However, this isn't working.

Do I  need to delete() as well? Will my code make the the whole vector disappear, (do I need to save the vector somehow?)
My tests show that it is either not freeing the memory, or deleting the entire vector.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `vector`? Can you show the full declaration of `vector` (as in `std::vector<T> vector`)? And please describe what you mean by "isn't working".

Comment: I added some more detail

Comment: there is no element in the vector ?

Comment: Is this the whole code? Because if it is, then vector is empty so this operation will naturally fail. If this *isn't* the whole code then please do post all the relevant lines.

Comment: it gets filled with different ints throughout the program and I check if it empty beforehand. It is part of a big program so, it's hard to sum it all up.

Comment: My most important observation is that this is not how you write comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::vector<T>` class looks after its own content and destroys the contained objects. Destroying a pointer means "do nothing". If you want to object pointed to by an element to be deleted automatically, you'd need to use something which looks after the `delete`, e.g., a `std::unique_ptr<T>`:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(new int(17));
vec.erase(vec.begin());
```

... or you'll need to explicitly look after `delete`ing the elements.

As an aside: erasing objects at the front of a `std::vector<T>` is rather inefficient! If you actually try to implement something like a queue, you are much better off using `std::queue<T>` or, if you need random access to the elements `std::deque<T>`. While `std::vector<T>` needs to shuffle all elements after the position being erased forward, `std::deque<T>` can efficiently erase at the front and the end.

Comment: Thank you! :)
You triggered the right idea in my head and fixed it